# Test::Unit and .first method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a test:

```
 def setup
    @cart = FactoryGirl.create(:cart_with_1_row)
  end

  test "should get show" do
    sign_in(FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true))
    FactoryGirl.create(:product_request)
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    get :show, id: @cart.id
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:product_requests)
  end
```

and a controller:

```
 def show
    cart = current_cart
    @product_requests = ProductRequest.find_all_by_cart_id(current_cart)
    cart.destroy
  end
```

And this fails unless I remove the following from my views:

```
<h6><%= @product_requests.first.user.first_name %> <%= @product_requests.first.user.last_name %></h6>
<h6><%= @product_requests.first.street %></h6>
<h6><%= @product_requests.first.city %>, <%= @product_requests.first.state %> <%= @product_requests.first.zip %></h6>
```

The error is:

```
  1) Error:
test_should_get_show(CartsControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

Which means calling user on .first is creating it? The page works fine in the development and production environment.

As a sanity check I put `<%= product_request.user.first_name %>` inside my each method on the ivar, and that worked. Am I interpreting this correctly that .first is the problem?

The view in question looks something like this:

```
<h6><%= @product_requests.first.user.first_name %> <%= @product_requests.first.user.last_name %></h6>
    <h6><%= @product_requests.first.street %></h6>
    <h6><%= @product_requests.first.city %>, <%= @product_requests.first.state %> <%= @product_requests.first.zip %></h6

<% @product_requests.each do |product_request| %>
<%= product_request.user.first_name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there - the problem here is that @product_requests is empty, so `@product_requests.first` returns nil and nil.first is indeed the problem.

I advice you to verify that `current_cart` is not nil itself - that's my guess for the cause.

Comment: How can `<%= product_request.user.first_name %>` work then if @product_requests is empty?

Comment: Are they on the same view? It will be helpful if you could add `<%= product_request.user.first_name %>` to the context of the code in the question. Aside from that, use a debugger and query for the current_cart  and @product_requests values in the controller.

Comment: I've added more context above. They are in the same view.

Comment: You are right. @product_requests is empty! How is that possible?

Comment: When you say `<%= product_request.user.first_name %>` do you mean it doesn't raise an exception? Because it won't raise an exception if @product_requests is empty, but @product_requests.first.user will raise an exception.

Comment: Verify that current_cart returns a valid cart and that's current_cart.product_requests is not equal to [] (empty)

Comment: I changed the line to `@product_requests = ProductRequest.find_all_by_cart_id(cart)` and it worked. Not sure why as current_cart on it's own line returned a valid cart.

Comment: cart does not respond to product_requests. Which isn't surprising, because Product_requests has the cart id, not the other way around.